# ssrs automatically running subreports for each value in dataset column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have been reading online articles for a few days and have tried a few things but am no further, so I am asking for help.

I have a Master report that takes an input OrderGroupID and returns a list of PreorderID's. In my test case my OrderGroupID returns three PreOrderID's.

I have two subreports that need to be run for each of these values. I have tested the Master report and so far I can only get it to get run the sub reports for the first PreorderID.

Comment: Possible answer. If you have a table grouped by the PreOrderID's, then in the detail row add the sub report. Set the input param to the value of the tables grouped PreOrderID's. When it runs it should run the each subreport for each value. Repeat the same for the second sub report.

Comment: This is a very sparse question. I wonder if it would be beneficial for you, especially if you have no other research avenues at the moment, to add your database `CREATE TABLE` statements (so readers can see the structure of your database) and the queries you are running? Perhaps also, a screenshot or other graphical representation. It is possible that someone with domain knowledge might see the problem, but in my experience, short questions tend to be skipped over.